# How to validate that a "confirm password" is the same than the password with angular Reactive

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I've to validate that I've two passwords matching.
I've found this solution: [Angular 11 How to validate confirmPassword is same as password using Reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231873/angular-11-how-to-validate-confirmpassword-is-same-as-password-using-reactive-fo) Which seems to work.

BUT: I'm using a component library, which automatically styles the component when its in error. The problem here is that my confirm password isn't going to red, since the error is attached to the whole form and not a specific field.

How can I do this:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="flex flex-column">
    <kendo-floatinglabel text="Password" class="w-auto m-2">
      <input kendoTextBox formControlName="password" type="password" />
    </kendo-floatinglabel>
    <kendo-floatinglabel text="Repeat password" class="w-auto m-2">
      <input
        kendoTextBox
        formControlName="confirmPassword"
        type="password"
      />
    </kendo-floatinglabel>
  </div>
</form>
```

with this component

```
  loginForm = this.fb.group(
    {
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    },
    { validators: this.confirmPasswordMatching }
  );

  passwordMatchingValidatior(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = control.get('password');
    const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword');
    return password?.value === confirmPassword?.value
      ? null
      : { notmatched: true };
  }
```

but have the error attached to the field instead?

Comment: Just put the validator on the `confirmPassword` control, instead of the whole form. You might need to adapt the code a little, since `control` won't be the whole form group anymore, just the `confirmPassword`. You do have access to parent control though

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I tried this, but then if I correct the other field(the password one), it doesn't re-run the confirmPasswordMatching

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [`setErrors`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#seterrors) on the `confirmPassword` control like this:

```
  passwordMatchingValidatior(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = control.get('password');
    const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword');
    const error = { notmatched: true };
    const isValid = password?.value === confirmPassword?.value;
    if (!isValid) {
      confirmPassword?.setErrors(error);
    }
    return isValid ? null : error;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here,

1. Access the input element and add/remove `ng-invalid` and `ng-valid` classes on the input based on the validity.
2. Listen to the form controls and manually set errors / remove errors.

Here would be an example for listening to the form control change and use `setErrors` to set/remove errors. Using a boolean variable `alive`, which set to `false` in `OnDestroy`.

```ts
get confirmPassword() {
  return this.loginForm.get('confirmPassword') as FormControl;
}

ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([
    this.loginForm.get('password').valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
    this.loginForm.get('confirmPassword').valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
  ])
  .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
  .subscribe((values: [string, string]) => {
    if (!values[1]) {
      this.confirmPassword.setErrors({ required: true });
      return;
    } else if (values[0] !== values[1]) {
      this.confirmPassword.setErrors({ notmatched: true });
      return;
    }
    this.confirmPassword.setErrors(null);
  });
}
```

So this option does not have a custom validator at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[showErrorIcon]="!loginForm.valid"` in your "confirmPassword input". See the [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/TextBoxComponent/#toc-showerroricon)

```
    <kendo-textbox id="confirm"
        [style.width.px]="350"
        formControlName="confirmPassword"
        [showErrorIcon]="!form.valid && form.get('confirmPassword').touched"
        [clearButton]="true"

        >
    </kendo-textbox>
```

To "bordered red" you can use .css. if your confirmpassword has a id="confirm"

```
form.ng-invalid #confirm.ng-touched
{
  border-color:red
}
form.ng-invalid #confirm.ng-touched .k-icon
{
  color:red
}
```